# Activate subform for data entry using a button on main form

Tags: ms-access, vba

How can I reference a button click event on the main form to a subform, similar to:

```
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
```

I want to use the subform both for viewing and entering new records but my button is on the main form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SetFocus` to the subform control, then do `GoToRecord`.

```vb
Private Sub cmdAddSubRow_Click()
    Me.SubControlName.SetFocus
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
End Sub
```

Replace *SubControlName* with the name of the subform *control*, not the name of the form which is contained in that control.  This is an important point which often trips people up.